# How to print all possible combinations of a list that have the same sum as the original list?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, while-loop, python-itertools

I am trying to print all possible combinations of a list but only if the combinations add up to a number.

```
lst = [0, 1, 2] #The goal is print all combinations that sum up to 3

import itertools

def fun(lst, total):
    sum = 0
    for element in lst:
        sum += element
        all_possible_combinations = set(itertools.product(lst, repeat=2)) # This prints all possible combinations of the elements in the list with length of 2
        for items in all_possible_combinations:
            a = 0
            for i in items:
                a += i
            if a == total:
                x = items
                print(x)
    print('These are all combinations:', all_possible_combinations)

fun([0, 1, 2], 2)
```

This programme prints the lists with a sum of 3 but it prints these lists more than once.

```
>>>>>>>>
(2, 0)
(1, 1)
(0, 2)  #I was expecting the programme to stop here.
(2, 0)
(1, 1)
(0, 2)
(2, 0)
(1, 1)
(0, 2)
These are all combinations: {(0, 1), (1, 2), (0, 0), (2, 1), (2, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (1, 0), (0, 2)}
>>>>>>>>
```

I thought that this was because of the `for element in lst:` loop so I tried to print outside this loop

```
import itertools

def fun(lst, total):
    sum = 0
    for element in lst:
        sum += element
        all_possible_combinations = set(itertools.product(lst, repeat=2)) # This prints all possible combinations of the elements in the list with length of 2
        for items in all_possible_combinations:
            a = 0
            for i in items:
                a += i
            if a == total:
                x = items
    print(x)
    print('These are all combinations:', all_possible_combinations)

fun([0, 1, 2], 2)
```

This programme only returns one of the lists

```
>>>>>>>>>
(0, 2)
>>>>>>>>>
```

How do I correct this? I am expecting the final result to be

```
>>>>>>>>>
(2, 0)
(1, 1)
(0, 2)
>>>>>>>>>
```

Comment: You seem to have your requirements messed up. You say you want combinations that sum to the total of the list... but then you pass a total in. Which is it? The problem is partially that `for`... you do your entire algorithm for each item in the list. Try using `sum(lst)` and skip those adding for loops completely. Your code will be more clear.

Comment: Ya I had the same doubt, so I added a `sum_list` variable in my answer(Change it based on your actual requirement). Also do you only require those lists of length = 2? Please make appropriate changes.

Comment: For the total, its better to make this an argument because it could change from time to time. The length of the lists can be more than 2 but this is a very simplified version which has helped me think and actually solve the real problem. Thank you very much

Comment: I have edited the question to reflect this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly you just keep overwriting the values, leaving you only the last value of x. Creating an array and appending the items to this array should show all results.

```
import itertools

def fun(lst, total):
    sum = 0
    for element in lst:
        sum += element
        x = []
        all_possible_combinations = set(itertools.product(lst, repeat=2)) # This prints all possible combinations of the element in the list with length of 2
        for items in all_possible_combinations:
            a = 0
            for i in items:
                a += i
            if a == total:
                x.append(items)
    print(x)
    print('These are all combinations:', all_possible_combinations)

fun([0, 1, 2], 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Let the list be `l = [0, 1, 2]` and `sum_list = sum(l)` EDIT: Sorry read it wrong initialy

Then you could do:

```
import itertools as it

for i in range(len(l)):
    ans = list(filter(lambda x: sum(x)==sum_list, list(it.combinations(l, i)))

print ans
```

Comment: Plus those are not all combinations but only those of length 2 right? So if you make bigger lists your code won't scale. I hope it satisfies your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You actually just need to take the loop over the elements out, since your `all_possible_combinations` does in fact have all combinations of 2-tuples in the list. When you loop over `lst`, it repeats the process the length of the list, hence the repetitions in the output.

Revised first version:

```
import itertools

def fun(lst, total):
        all_possible_combinations = set(itertools.product(lst, repeat=2)) # This prints all possible combinations of the elements in the list with length of 2
        for items in all_possible_combinations:
            a = 0
            for i in items:
                a += i
            if a == total:
                x = items
                print(x)
        print('These are all combinations:', all_possible_combinations)

fun([0, 1, 2], 2)
```

Output:

```
>>> fun([0, 1, 2], 2)
(1, 1)
(2, 0)
(0, 2)
('These are all combinations:', set([(0, 1), (1, 2), (0, 0), (2, 1), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 2), (1, 0), (0, 2)]))
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
import itertools

a = [0, 1, 2]

result = [b for b in itertools.product(a, repeat=2) if sum(b)<=sum(a)]
```

And to get what you wanted, this is the code:

```
import itertools

a = [0, 1, 2]

result = [b for b in itertools.product(a, repeat=2) if sum(b)<sum(a) and sum(b)>1]
print result
```